Conjugacy action of $SO(2m)$ on $O(2m)/U(m)$
I seek intuition about the symmetric space $S$, the set of orthogonal complex structures in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for even $n=2m$.
I am finding J.H.Eschenburg's Lecture Notes on Symmetric Spaces very helpful. They show that $S=O(n)\cap A(n)=\{j\in A(n)|j^2=-I\}$ where $A(n)$ are the skew-symmetric matrices. Furthermore, $S\cong O(2m)/U(m)$. I am trying to understand the footnote to Example 7, where $j\in S$ and they explain that

the conjugacy class of $j$ with respect to $SO(n)$ is strictly
smaller than the $O(n)$-conjugacy class

Given $j_1,j_2\in S$, I understand that there is a single conjugacy class with regard to $O(n)$.  Let $J$ be the standard complex structure of $\mathbb{R}^{n}=\mathbb{C}^m$, written
$$J=\textrm{diag}\begin{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\dots,\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\end{bmatrix}$$
I can write $j_1=B_1JB_1^{-1}, j_2=B_2JB^{-1}$ for some $B_1,B_2\in O(n)$. Then $j_1=B_1B_2^{-1}j_2B_2B_1^{-1}$.  Thus all elements in $S$ are conjugate to each other with regard to $O(n)$.
How do I show that there exist $j_1,j_2\in S$ for which $j_1\neq sj_2s^{-1}$ for all $s\in SO(n)$ ?
I suspect that there are two conjugacy classes but I don't know how to show them or define them.  Thank you for helping me. I appreciate your intuition!

As written, it makes no sense since $SO(n)$ does not act on $S$ by conjugation. Are you sure you are quoting correctly?

@MoisheKohan Thank you for asking.  I will quote more:  "Let $S$ be the set of orthogonal complex structures in $R^n$ for even $n = 2m$.  ... $S = O(n) ∩ A(n) = {j ∈ A(n); j 2 = −I}$ ($A(n)$ are the skew-symmetric matrices.) Moreover, since any $j ∈ S$ is an orthogonal matrix with eigenvalues $+i, −i$ of multiplicity
$m$, all $j$’s are conjugate and $S$ is a conjugacy class, an orbit under the action of $O(n)$ by conjugation. The isotropy group of the standard complex structure $i$ of $R^{2m} = C^m$ is the unitary group $U (m) ⊂ O(2m)$."  Then there is the footnote.

The footnote says: "In particular, $S\cong O(2m)/U (m)$ has two connected components like $O(2m)$ since $U(m)$ is connected. Unlike the situation in the previous example (AK: Grassmannians), the conjugacy class of $j$ with respect to $SO(n)$ is strictly smaller than the $O(n)$-conjugacy class."  I am trying to figure out that last sentence, what it means, why "strictly smaller" is true, intuitively and concretely.

Diffeomorphic to, not equal!

@MoisheKohan Thank you! I have changed it in my question.  Also, I noticed that at the bottom of my question I was using $S$ to mean an entirely different thing, a matrix.  So I have changed that to $s$. I am sorry for that. Thank you for correcting me!

You did not fix it. Now, $S$ is simply left undefined in your post and one needs to read your comment to figure out what it actually is. And even then, you mixed up $n$ and $m$. You have to spend more time formulating your question properly if you want any help.

Here is a hint: Consider orthogonal complex structures on the plane ($n=2$ or $n=1$ depending on how you clean up your notation). You will find exactly two.

@MoisheKohan Thank you for alerting me to my errors. I have corrected my post. Thank you also for the hint. I will think about that.


As I suggested in a hint, it is useful to consider first the case $n=2$. Then there are exactly two order 4 rotations in the plane, namely, $J_1$ and $-J_1$ (rotations by $\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$). They are obviously not conjugate by any element of $SO(2)$ since this group is commutative, but they are conjugate by an element of $O(2)$, namely, any reflection.

Consider now almost complex structures on $\mathbb R^n$, $n=2m\ge 4$. One can take, for instance,
$$
J= J_1\oplus J_1\oplus .... \oplus J_1
$$
($m$-fold sum) as one complex structure and
$$
J'= (-J_1)\oplus J_1 .... \oplus J_1
$$
as the other one. Then $J'$ is conjugate to $J$ by a reflection $R$ (say, the one fixing the coordinate hyperplane $x_1=0$). This reflection, of course, does not belong to $SO(n)$. Moreover, $J'$ clearly belongs to the component of $S\cong O(n)/U(n)$ which is different from the component $SO(n)/U(n)$ containing $J$ (since $R$ does not belong to the identity component of $O(n)$, which is $SO(n)$). In particular, $J'$ cannot be obtained from $J$ by conjugation via an element of $SO(n)$.


That's all what there is to it.

Thank you for your knowledgeable reply and for writing this out so clearly!
